# how to pass Class B variable to class A,if class A extends Class B

Tags: java

extending class B in Class A, now I am printing value of variable a in Class A.The result i am getting is a=0 . How can i get the value a=2

Class A

```
package testing;

public class ClassA extends ClassB {

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("a= " +a);
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        ClassA ca = new ClassA();
        ca.print();

    }
}
```

Class B

```
package testing;

public class ClassB {
int a;
public void send(){
    a=2;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially the value of `a` is `0`, as you have not set it to anything, and by default, when you call `new ClassA();` it is initialized to 0. Hence you get `0` as the output.

You need to call the `send` method, to set the value of `a` to `2`.

```
ClassA ca = new ClassA();
ca.send(); //Here
ca.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easier way to understanding of parsing of variables between classes is using the get-set methods.

Class A coding:

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB {    
public static void main (String [] args)
{        
    ClassB ClassBValue = new ClassB();
    System.out.println(ClassBValue.getA());
}
```

}

Class B coding:

```
public class ClassB {
     int A = 2;       
    public int getA()
    {
        return A;
    }
    public void setAValue(int A)
    {
        this.A = A;
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ca.print()` without assigning any value to it, so basically it is printing initialized value for `int` a which is 0.

Put a call to `send()` before the print function, Compiler will first check for function send in `ClassA`, when it does not find it there it will call send function of the SuperClass which is B, this will assign value '2' to your variable a, When you call `print()`, print function present in Class A is called, Now Class A has no variable called a, so the value of variable a is called from it's super class and you will get value of 2 printed.

Code should look like ->

```
    public class ClassA extends ClassB {

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("a= " +a);
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        ClassA ca = new ClassA();
        ca.send();
        ca.print();

    }
}

public class ClassB {
int a;


public void send(){
    a=2;
}
}
```

Comment: The code shouldn't look like that at all. OP's formatting is horrible.

Comment: But what if call send() then "send()" method has many more functions inside .if I do like above it will call /execute other methods/logic also .then what to do

Comment: Any one answer my doubt?

Answer (score 0):

Your int variables, by default, are initialized with 0.

Some options:

A) Alter your main method to call the send method

```
    ClassA ca = new ClassA();
    ca.send(); //set the value to 2
    ca.print();
```

B) If don't want to alter your main method (for any reason), you can move the variable initialization to the class construtor:

```
    ClassA() {
      a = 2
    }
```

Now, when you instantiate your the class (new ClassA()), 'a' gonna be equals 2.